# iOS ViewController doesn't layout properly after orientation change

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rotation, orientation

I'm writing an iOS application with some fixed (portrait) views and some orientation dependent views (portrait, lanscape left and landscape right).

The views are contained in a Custom Navigation Controller based on the following code:

```
class CustomNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate()
    }
}
```

I'm implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` and `shouldAutorotate()` inside nav child controllers.

Here is a Test Controller

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    var shouldRotate: Bool = false

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        self.shouldRotate = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    convenience init(rotation shouldRotate: Bool) {
        self.init(nibName: "TestViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.shouldRotate = shouldRotate
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if shouldRotate == false {
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
        } else {
            return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return shouldRotate
    }

    override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        println("from: \(fromInterfaceOrientation.rawValue)")
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let newvc = TestViewController(rotation: true)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newvc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The first controller is instantiated inside the `AppDelegate` with `rotation: false`. The other controllers are created with `rotation: true` and pushed after tapping the button.

Here is a screenshot of the view:

[image: first controller]

If I change orientation on the controllers after the first one (the rotable ones) I get the following result:

[image: rotated controller]

The controller xib uses autolayout and **if I rotate the device before tapping the button it works as expected** with the view filling the whole screen.

Also, if I tap the back button while the phone is in landscape the first view is locked in this state:

[image]

I'm deploying the app to iOS 8.

How can I make the first view portrait only and the other views correctly layed out after a rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably doesn't matter since it's only printing out a debug message, but don't forget that `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(_:)` was depreciated in iOS 8 with `viewWillTransitionToSize(_:withTransitionCoordinator:)` taking it's place for responsibilities of a change in view size (which includes rotation).

I think you're on the right track, but instead of overriding both `shouldAutorotate()` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` only override `supportedInterfaceOrientations()`.

I just did a quick POC to see if it would work. I'm not setting a flag when creating the view controller (and using Swift 2) but you get the idea:

```
class RotatingViewController: UIViewController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
}

class FixedViewController: UIViewController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
}

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations() ?? UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
}
```

I think what's happening in your demo is that when you're transitioning to a view controller that is fixed, you're asking it to go into a portrait orientation (which it is) but then not allowing the screen to rotate back to portrait mode.

So.. just try deleting your 'shouldAutorotate()' in your `CustomNavigationViewController` and see if that works.

Comment: I've updated the test project to swift 2 and Xcode 7 then changed `shouldAutorotate()` to return `true`. Now it works as expected. The strange thing is that the correct return value was commented in my project so I'm sure I had already tested this solution but for some reason didn't worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because `shouldAutorotate` return `false`.
Your FixedViewController should return `shouldAutorotate` value `true`, but `supportedInterfaceOrientations` should be for example only portrait.

Why do you need it?
When you come back (by using `popViewController` or `dismissViewController`) to your  FixedViewController (which supports only portrait mode) from another RotateViewController in landscape mode, it should autorotate, to come back to portrait mode